# No Carga DataTable de Bootstrap en proyecto con Django

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, django, datatable

tengo problemas para hacer funcionar el DataTable de Bootstrap en mi proyecto de Django, es la que usa en la plantilla que se puede ver aca  https://startbootstrap.com/previews/sb-admin-2/
Los datos cargan bien, la hice al principio con una tabla estilos de Bootstrap sin la DataTable, pero cuando agrego el script del DataTable parece que no la toma. *NO muestra error*, solo que no muestra los datos en dicho DataTable, ver imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PLANTILLA**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Codigo de la pagina html "hija" donde esta el DataTable

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% block page_content %}
<!-- Aqui estan los datos de la tabla id="CatTabla" -->
{% endblock page_content %}
{% block js_pagina %}
<script>
  //--Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#CatTabla').DataTable();
  });
</script>
{% endblock js_pagina %}
```

**Fragmento de la pagina "padre" base.html** :

```
</head>
  {% load static %}

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="{% static 'base/css/sb-admin-2.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this page  DATATABLES-->
  <link href="{% static 'base/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

 </head> 
 <body>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
  <script src="{% static 'base/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'base/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="{% static 'base/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js' %}"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="{% static 'base/js/sb-admin-2.min.js' %}"></script>

  <!-- Page level plugins DATATABLES-->
  <script src="{% static 'base/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'base/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Prueba quitando esta libreria `dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js` deja la que viene por defecto, es decir `jquery.dataTables.min.js` y nos cuentas si el error persiste

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo Jheyman-mejia. 
Eliminé la librería, pero sigue sin cargar el Datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error estaba en la tabla, tenia un cierre de contenedor mal

**ERROR:**

```
...
</tr>
<td>{{item.fm|date:"d/m/Y H:m:s"}}</td>                   
<td>
    <a href="#"...
    <a href="#" ...
</td>
```

**CORRECCION:**

```
...
<td>{{item.fm|date:"d/m/Y H:m:s"}}</td>                   
<td>
    <a href="#"...
    <a href="#" ...
</td>
</tr>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]